# Sqlite Not updating

Tags: android

Here is my Code

```
 String Query= " UPDATE  Subjects  SET  Subjects ='"+newSubject + " Where UserName='"+ Username + "'" +"AND Subjects ='"+oldSubject+"'" ;

    database.execSQL(Query,null);
```

it does not update

Comment: Are you quite sure that the `newSubject` and the `oldSubject` values are set to the right values, so does an `oldSubject` exist in the database?

Comment: Mind single quotes and spaces in your query. Instead, I would suggest you to use `database.update()` method

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code I beleive there is an error

Old Code

```
String Query= " UPDATE  Subjects  SET  Subjects ='"+newSubject + " Where UserName='"+ Username + "'" +"AND Subjects ='"+oldSubject+"'" ;
```

You missed a `'` in your `SET` method

Try this

```
String Query= " UPDATE  Subjects  SET  Subjects ='"+newSubject + "' Where UserName='"+ Username + "' AND Subjects ='"+oldSubject+"'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whereclause is probably not returning anything, therefore the update does not work.

Also consider using `update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` instead of a raw query.